# How to upload audio file from android to server through .net webservice?

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

We have a web application made in MVC3 which is hosted in Android & Iphone also .Now the android developer is trying to upload an audio file through our method which is written in controller as http post method . They say they are sending the file in form of multipart chunks or byte buffer body . So I took variable of type byte array[] in my method but the type is not coinciding with their datatype .  I even tried to keep string , byte , httppostedfilebase types , but still no success . Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [VoiceModel](http://voicemodel.codeplex.com/) open source project for an example of how to save audio using ASP.NET MVC. There is an example project in there called [RecordingExample](http://voicemodel.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/20136) which takes an audio file sent from a VoiceXML browser or Interactive Voice Response (IVR) systems and saves it to the file system.  Here is the code that receives the audio file and saves it to disk.

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SaveRecording(HttpPostedFileBase CallersMessage)
 {
     if (CallersMessage != null && CallersMessage.ContentLength > 0)
     {
         // extract only the fielname
         var fileName = Path.GetFileName(CallersMessage.FileName);
         // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
         var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(recordingPath), fileName);
         _log.Debug("Received recording and will save as " + path);
         CallersMessage.SaveAs(path);
     }

     string vm_id = Request.QueryString["vm_id"];
     string vm_event = Request.QueryString["vm_event"];
     string vm_result = "";
     return VoiceView(vm_id, vm_event, vm_result);
 }
```

Comment: I already tried with httppostedfilebase , but I couldn't capture what the android guy sends me as there was type mismatch . He is passing me  chunk data or you can say multipart data . I have to interpret that datatype in order to operate upload at server .

Comment: VoiceXML browsers also send the audio as multipart data and this works fine. What are the errors you are getting when you try to retrieve it this way?  Exactly how does it fail.

Comment: The encoding type used for sending the audio file is "multipart/form-data". What does the code look like in the Android app to send this?

Comment: code is almost similar to the site http://www.androidsnippets.com/download-an-http-file-to-sdcard-with-progress-notification

Comment: That code shows how to receive a file on the android device over http, not send a file from android.